# Would like to match the zip code in a form to the corresponding state

Tags: javascript

I am new at these things. I am trying to write a function that will make sure that the state  entered in the form by a user match the zip code he/she entered.
For example the zip codes of my state (Wisconsin, WI) are between 53000 and 54999, so I would like to make sure that if the zip code entered in the form is between 53000 and 54999, the state entered is WI, if not the user is alerted.My html and code are below:It turns the string zip code into numbers but the part that is supposed to compare the zip code and the state is not working. How do I use the test() Method to compare the state entered to the real state that correspond to the zip code? Thanks.
....................................................................

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> Matching state and zip code</title>

<script>
function validate(form) {
var returnValue = true;
var state = form.txtState.value;
var zip = form.txtZipcode.value;
var nzip = parseInt("form.txtZipcode.value");


if (state.length !=2) {
returnValue = false;
alert("The state field is empty. Please enter a state.");
frmRegister.txtState.focus();
}
if ((nzip >= 5300 && nzip <=5499) && (state !== WI)){
returnValue = false;
alert("The zip code does not match the state. Please check again");
frmRegister.txtState.focus();
}

if (zip.length !==5) {
returnValue = false;
alert("Your zip code should be \n 5 digits long. Please enter a real US zip code");
frmRegister.txtZipcode.focus();
}

if (typeof nzip == "string") { 
alert('nzip is a string.') 
}
if (typeof nzip == "number") { 
alert('nzip is a number.') 
}

else
return returnValue;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name ="frmRegister" method="post"  action ="register.aspx"
onsubmit="return validate(this);">

<fieldset>
<legend>Register with us</legend>

<div> 
<label for ="txtState"> STATE:</label>
<input type="text" name="txtState" id ="txtState" size = "12"/>
</div>

<div> 
<label for ="txtZipcode"> ZIP CODE:</label>
<input type="text" name="txtZipcode" id ="txtZipcode" size = "12"/>
</div>

<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this checking by storing the range of zipcode values in a JSON array, like

```
var states = {WI : {start : 5000,end:6000}, ST : {start: 6001,end: 7000}};
```

Now get the value of state, let it be "state_entered", now get the range as

```
var range = states.state_entered;
```

Now the range checking is easier

```
if(zipcode_entered > range.start && zipcode_entered < range.end){
   alert("That's correct!!!");
}
```

This way you can handle any number of states without the code being cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks. I will check and let you know.Checking The validity of the zip code per se is not really my biggest problem: What is giving the headache is to compare the zip code entered with the state to make sure that the two match. Let say a person enter 53704 (a Wisconsin (WI) zip code) but select Michigan (MI) as state, I want the function to:

Comment: I will check and let you know.Checking The validity of the zip code per se is not really my biggest problem: What is giving the headache is to compare the zip code entered with the state to make sure that the two match. Let say a person enter 53704 (a Wisconsin (WI) zip code) but select Michigan (MI) as state, I want the function to: get the zip code, test if it's between 53000 and 54999, get the two letters of the state selected (in this case MI) compare it to the known state with the zip code, and if it matches the form is submitted, if not(like in this case) alert goes on.